# How can I remove all these symbols from this text?

Tags: windows-7, windows, dll

I have [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcn46881d9vnkqd/patchw32.dll) dll file. When I read it in a hex editor, it reads as [this text](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/w8158yvktetpxyr/patchw32.dll.txt).

How do I remove all the symbols, while keeping the readable words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the unix utility `strings` that is also packaged for windows in cygwin as `strings.exe`

Answer (score 0):

- You might try MS-Word [Recover text from any file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290946) feature.
- String data references can be also extracted by a debugger (e.g. URSoft W32
  debugger /very old, commercial/).
- Symbols (function names) can be
  read by [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).
- [Resource hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) /free/ also
  seems to provide pretty readable text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sysinternals strings utility from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx.